# Does using include in PHP to remove parts of code that's currently not being used reduce memory consumption?

Tags: php, memory, optimization

If a part of code is only used when someone is signed in, in a PHP file, can memory be reduced by removing that code from the file, putting it in another PHP file, and instead including it with PHP `include` inside an `if` condition?

Comment: Assuming the included php file is of non trivial size, this method could speed up execution time of your "primary" php file in the case of the if statement condition evaluating to false.